# $L^p$ norm of a measurable function is bounded by its operation on step functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $1\leq p<\infty$, $1/p+1/q=1$. Let $f$ be a measurable function on $[0,1]$ such that for all step functions $g$ on $[0,1]$
>   $$
> \left|\int_0^1 fg d\mu\right|\leq \|g\|_q.
> $$
>   Prove that $\|f\|_p\leq 1$.

I have tried following, but failed:

Let $F_f: L^q[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle F_f(g)=\int_0^1 fg $. If for all $g\in L^q[0,1]$ $$
\left|\int_0^1 fg d\mu\right|\leq \|g\|_q, 
$$
then $$\|f\|_p=\|F_f\|=\sup_{\|g\|_q\neq 0}\frac{|F_f(g)|}{\|g\|_q}\leq 1.$$
Hence we only need to prove for all $g\in L^q[0,1]$ $$
\left|\int_0^1 fg d\mu\right|\leq \|g\|_q.
$$
Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a sequence of step functions such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|\phi_n-g\|_q=0$. I want to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f\phi_n d\mu=\int_0^1 fg d\mu$. Then the wanted inequality of $g$ would be obtained.

If $f$ is in $L^p[0,1]$, then by Holder inequality, 
$$
\left|\int_0^1 f(\phi_n-g) d\mu\right|\leq \|f\|_p\|\phi_n-g\|_q\to \|f\|_p\cdot 0=0.
$$
Thus we obtain the proof.

Hence we only need to prove $f\in L^p[0,1]$.  How should I continue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to consider for $N \in \Bbb{N}$ the "truncated" function $\tilde{f} := f \cdot \chi_{|f| \leq N}$.

As you are on a measure space with finite measure, it is then clear that $\tilde{f} \in L^p$. Furthermore, your assumption also holds for $\tilde{f}$, because of

$$
\bigg|\int \tilde{f} \cdot g \,dx \bigg| = \bigg|\int f \cdot (g \cdot \chi_{|f| \leq N}) \, dx \bigg| \leq \Vert g \cdot \chi_{|f| \leq N}\Vert_q \leq \Vert g \Vert_q.
$$

Also note that $g \cdot \chi_{|f| \leq N}$ is a step function, if $g$ is.

You can then conclude $\Vert \tilde{f} \Vert_p \leq 1$ and use the monotone convergence theorem to conclude the proof.

Comment: $g\chi_{\{|f|\leq N\}}$ is a simple function, not necessarily a step function.

Comment: What are your exact definitions of these therms? They are often used interchangeable. If you are concerned for the finite measure of the "steps" note that if the steps of $g$ are of finite measure, the same is true of $g \cdot \chi_{|f| \leq N}$.

Comment: step functions take constant value on finitely many intervals, simple functions take constant value on finitely many measurable sets. A step function is also a simple function, but the converse is not true. Take $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$, it is a simple function, but not a step function.

Comment: Ok, with that definition my proof would break down. But step functions are often defined differently (in context with Lebesgue integration), see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/sequence-of-step-maps-which-converge-almost-everywhere

Comment: I found this answer helpful, not sure if yall could help me with this problem~ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977249/proving-lpr-l-%CE%BB-is-separable-by-using-step-functions-with-finite-support